# Keyboard switch

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

Ubuntu 13.10
I like switching by left shift + alt.
And it works. But only in that succession.
Does not react on reversed or simultaneous press.

How to fix, or do I want too much?

Answer (score 0):

In 13.10, the keyboard switching is in *System Settings >> Text Entry*. The keyboards are now referred to as `input sources`. Please note that this is a different location than earlier Ubuntu versions.

There were some bugs related to input source switching when 13.10 was first released, so please make sure you have updated your system.

You can change the accelerators to switch input sources by clicking in the box labelled: *Switch to next source using*. This key sequence will cycle forward through your list of input sources.

You can change the accelerators to cycle in reverse by clicking in the box labelled: *Switch to previous source using*.

[image: Text Entry input source settings]

Based your question, you may want to use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> to go forward. I also set <kbd>Shfit</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Please note one quick: the combo for the previous source only says <kbd>Alt</kbd>, but it will only work with the actual key (<kbd>Left Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>) that you pressed when setting the combo.

If you have a lot of input sources and don't want to cycle through them in order to get to the one you one, make sure `Show current input source in the menu bar` is checked. It should be checked by default. This will let you use the menubar indicator to jump to the input source you need.

Note that the input switching is separate from input entry methods like `ibus`.